# NestJS multer file upload ends in pending request

Tags: nestjs, multer

I have a weird case where i cannot find a way to make file upload work properly using NestJS, MulterModule and @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor()).
All requests to file upload route end in an infinite pending request (Seen on browser console).

I can safely state that this is not a frontend bug as it works fine with a workaround that i found (an ugly one).

This is the 3rd project where i have the same problem, but i'd like to avoid using the workaround that i found.

**The case that IS NOT working is the following:**

Concerning AppModule configuration:

```
MulterModule.register({
  dest: "./upload",
})
```

Concerning route =>

```
@Post(":id/files")
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
async saveCustomerFile(
  @Param("id") id: string,
  @Body() body: DtoSaveCustomerFile,
  @UploadedFile()
  uploadedFile: Express.Multer.File,
) {
  console.log("===================================")
  console.log("===================================")
  console.log("===================================")
  console.log("===================================")

  if (!uploadedFile) {
    throw new BadRequestException("missing file!")
  }

  // do stuff...

  return { data: file }
}
```

**The case that IS working is the following:**

Concerning AppModule configuration:

```
No MulterModule registration, it is imported directly in main.ts through
app.use(multer({dest: "./upload"}).single("file"))
```

Concerning route =>

```
Almost the same, except that i remove @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
```

I must point that i had the same problem on various main versions of NestJS (currently 9).

Multer versions tested are 1.4.4 and 1.4.5.

I suspected it would be do to a ValidationPipe configuration option:

```
whitelist: true
```

But even set to false changed nothing.

If someone could help, it would really be helpful!
Thanks.